# Hacer una repetición de un número con decimales x veces. Python

Tags: python

Buenos días, tengo un problema al hacer un vector de repetición con números decimales. Para hacerlo de números enteros uso esto `x0=numpy.repeat(0, 100)`
que genera en este caso una lista de 100 ceros. El problema viene cuando quiero por ejemplo que la lista se la repetición de un número decimal por ejemplo `1/120` intento poner esto pero no me lo genera `x0=numpy.repeat((0/120), 100)`.

Muchas gracias a todos, saludos.

Comment: Fran, `repeat` es una función propia? te recomiendo que agregues el código de la misma a la pregunta. Por otro lado el problema puede tener que ver con  el casteo a enteros, prueba hacer esto `(1.0/120)`

Comment: Hola Fran, ¿Qué es lo que te retorna?¿Usas Python 2?. Recuerda en que en Python 2 el operador `/` aplicado a enteros retorna la división entera (floor division). Supongo que `repeat` es el método `numpy.repeat`.

Comment: perdón es un numpy,     numpy.repeat(0,100)

Comment: Gracias Patricio Moracho era por eso que me has dicho, muchas gracias :)